# Facing an error when running my android app on an emulator

Tags: android, react-native

Hi I'm just starting to learn how to code on android studio.

After running npm run android on my terminal, I've faced some errors which I could not solve.

The error message is as follows :

> XXXX-MacBook-Pro:first-app XXXX$ npm run android
>
> first-app@0.1.0 android /Users/XXXX/Desktop/React Native/first-app 
>   react-native run-android
>
> Scanning folders for symlinks in /Users/XXXX/Desktop/React
>   Native/first-app/node_modules (8ms) Starting JS server... Building and
>   installing the app on the device (cd android && ./gradlew
>   installDebug)...
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> What went wrong: Could not resolve all files for configuration
>   ':app:_internal_aapt2_binary'.  Could not find
>   com.android.tools.build:aapt2:3.2.0-4818971.   Searched in the
>   following locations:
>         file:/Users/XXXX/Library/Android/sdk/extras/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.2.0-4818971/aapt2-3.2.0-4818971.pom
>         file:/Users/XXXX/Library/Android/sdk/extras/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.2.0-4818971/aapt2-3.2.0-4818971-osx.jar
>         file:/Users/XXXX/Library/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.2.0-4818971/aapt2-3.2.0-4818971.pom
>         file:/Users/XXXX/Library/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.2.0-4818971/aapt2-3.2.0-4818971-osx.jar
>         file:/Users/XXXX/Library/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.2.0-4818971/aapt2-3.2.0-4818971.pom
>         file:/Users/XXXX/Library/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.2.0-4818971/aapt2-3.2.0-4818971-osx.jar
>         file:/Users/XXXX/.m2/repository/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.2.0-4818971/aapt2-3.2.0-4818971.pom
>         file:/Users/XXXX/.m2/repository/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.2.0-4818971/aapt2-3.2.0-4818971-osx.jar
>         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.2.0-4818971/aapt2-3.2.0-4818971.pom
>         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.2.0-4818971/aapt2-3.2.0-4818971-osx.jar
>         file:/Users/XXXX/Desktop/React Native/first-app/node_modules/react-native/android/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.2.0-4818971/aapt2-3.2.0-4818971.pom
>         file:/Users/XXXX/Desktop/React Native/first-app/node_modules/react-native/android/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.2.0-4818971/aapt2-3.2.0-4818971-osx.jar
>   Required by:
>         project :app
>
> BUILD FAILED in 3s 11 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 10 up-to-date
>   Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for
>   details.

I hope you guys can help me with it.

Answer (score 7):

I managed to fix this issue by adding a line `google()` to `~/my-app/android/build.gradle` in the following section:

```
allprojects {
    respositories{
        google() //right here
    }
}
```

Just a guess, but I believe it is a regression to do with the new Android Studio 3.2.0 release.

Comment: I do have google() in my build.gradle file, and I think that you're right! I faced this error after updating my Android Studio to 3.2.0 after being prompted to do so.

Comment: +1 This change worked for me - `google()` wasn't in there by default for me. I also had to choose "Update Build Tools version and sync project" after syncing Gradle with the new change.

Comment: Found a similar answer (adding `google()` on this site: https://www.developerfaqs.com/3604/android-studio-3-2-could-not-find-com-android-tools-buildaapt23-2-0-4818971)

Comment: @InMyOwnWorld did you make sure `google()` was at the top of your repositories object?

Answer (score 1):

This is in react native which in fact i never used, this isn't an answer but i cant comment as my reputation is too low for that(pardon me). Have you installed android build tools? The ':app:_internal_aapt2_binary' is a configuration file that the system needs to compile the application which is a part of build tools.
 If you are using android studio 3.0, then in `gradle` , change the dependency from

```
compile files('xyz')
```

to

```
implementation files('xyz')
```

Comment: Hi I've changed the dependency to 'implementation' as I read from the release note. But after updating it to 3.2.0, I faced this error and I tried googling and trying out different solutions but to no avail. Could it be that 3.2.0 is a bugged release?

Comment: Hi, the release is not bugged in any case. Are you getting the exact same error?